# How to wait for a panicking goroutine?

Tags: go

A common way to wait for a goroutine is to use a `*sync.WaitGroup`:

```
func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        // Long running task
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

No problems here. However, what about this:

```
func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        // Long running task
        panic("Something unexpected happened.")
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

In this case, when `wg.Done()` is called, I believe `main()` could exit without details of `panic()` ever being written to `stdout`/`stderr`. Is this true and if yes, how might I prevent it from happening?

Comment: "I believe main() could exit without details of panic() ever being written to stdout/stderr". Your believe is wrong. With panic unrolling the stack main is no longer executing normally.

Comment: That belief is easily tested and proven wrong by just running the code: https://play.golang.org/p/yzfFfE0Y8iT

Comment: [Defer statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) run even if their function or goroutine panics (see the end of the first paragraph).

Comment: ITT: noone understanding the question. For anyone else with a similar problem: You can work around the uncertainty by writing a stack-trace yourself e.g. `logrus.Error(fmt.Sprintf("%v\n\n%s", "Something unexpected happened.", string(debug.Stack())))` (not entirely the same as the output of `panic()`, but good enough) and only then calling `Done()` on the wait group, letting your go routine terminate normally. If it does, it's good to know that recovering from panic leads to a blank return of the function longest in the call stack which encountered the panic. If it doesn't, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to provoke the unwanted behavior by adding `defer time.Sleep(time.Second)`:

```golang
func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer time.Sleep(time.Second)
        defer wg.Done()
        // Long running task
        panic("Something unexpected happened.")
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

```
D:\Projects\Code\Go\src\zyl\testexit>go build .
D:\Projects\Code\Go\src\zyl\testexit>.\testexit.exe
D:\Projects\Code\Go\src\zyl\testexit>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

The solution to the problem is to not defer the call to `Done()` and just place it at the end:

```golang
func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        // Long running task which might panic
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

In the above code, no dependency on implementation details of go routine behavior exists and will always fail when a panic occurs. After realizing this, I noticed the problem exists in about every tutorial on the subject ever written, meaning we are looking at a wide-spread manifestation of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 4):

The `panic` will kill the process regardless, because no one is recovering from it. If you want to recover from panics in a goroutine, you must have `recover` wrapping the call stack in the same goroutine.

`wg.Done` will be called in this case, by the `defer` statement. But the process may die before the main goroutine finishes the `wg.Wait` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

@Eli Bendersky was right.

Reference [src/builtin/builtin.go](https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go?h=panic#L227)

> The panic built-in function stops normal execution of the current
>   goroutine. When a function F calls panic, normal execution of F stops
>   immediately. Any functions whose execution was deferred by F are run in
>   the usual way, and then F returns to its caller. To the caller G, the
>   invocation of F then behaves like a call to panic, terminating G's
>   execution and running any deferred functions. This continues until all
>   functions in the executing goroutine have stopped, in reverse order. At
>   that point, the program is terminated and the error condition is reported,
>   including the value of the argument to panic. This termination sequence
>   is called panicking and can be controlled by the built-in function
>   recover.

after `panic`, `defer` func will be called.

Check this in playground: https://play.golang.org/p/yrXkEbE1Af7

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer func(){
            fmt.Println("expected to be called after panic")
            wg.Done()
        }()
        // Long running task
        panic("Something unexpected happened.")
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Output

```
expected to be called after panic
panic: Something unexpected happened.

goroutine 5 [running]:
main.main.func1(0x416020, 0x0)
    /tmp/sandbox946785562/main.go:17 +0x60
created by main.main
    /tmp/sandbox946785562/main.go:11 +0x80
```

Then your second question, "how to prevent that?"

As metioned before, you can `recover` after `panic`

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/76pPrCVYN8u

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer func(){
            if x:=recover();x!=nil{
                fmt.Printf("%+v\n",x)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
        // Long running task
        panic("Something unexpected happened.")
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    for i:=0;i<10;i++{
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Output

```
Something unexpected happened.
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```